# Configure CF11 with MAMP Pro

Tags: macos, apache, coldfusion-11, mamp-pro

## My Objective:

to install CF11 with an Apache web connector connected to MAMP Pro, such that I can add hosts via MAMP Pro that resolve to coldfusion web apps.

## My Environment:

- OSX 10.10.5 (Yosimite)
- ColdFusion 11
- MAMP 3.2.1

## My Problem:

I'm not really sure how to add an apache web connector for CF11. I've found the references below helpful, but they haven't really gotten me where I need to go. I think it boils down to this...

1. Run wsconfig by double clicking (`/Applications/ColdFusion11/cfusion/runtime/bin/wsconfig`)
2. Click "Add" to add a configured web server
3. AppServer Host: `localhost`
4. Web Server: `Apache`
5. Configuration Directory: `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf`
6. Advanced > Directory and file name of server binary `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/httpd`
7. Advanced > Directory and file name of server control script `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl`

At this point, I'd expect that I'd probably need to open MAMP and manually edit the httpd.conf file per the warning by Strick Insights below, but unfortunately I get this error. I have tried shutting down MAMP before committing the changes in case MAMP had a lock on the files, but that did NOT help.

[image: Error: Could not save changes to file /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/httpd.conf]

## My Question:

Is it obvious to anyone where I've gone wrong here? Any advice on what my next steps ought to be?

### References:

- [Adobe.com/Installing Help/Configuring your System](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/installing/configuring-your-system.html)
- [Configuring Coldfusion 10, Mamp Pro and Mac OS X 10.8](http://www.steckinsights.com/configuring-coldfusion-10-mamp-pro-and-mac-os-x-10-8/#.VlNKkd-rRTa) by Steck Insights Web Design
- [INSTALLING COLDFUSION 10 UNDER MAMP PRO 2 ON OS X LION](https://brilang.wordpress.com/2012/06/06/installing-coldfusion-10-under-mamp-pro-2-on-os-x-lion/) by Brian Lang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the command with sudo solves for the error.

```
$ sudo /Applications/ColdFusion11/cfusion/runtime/bin/wsconfig
```

Comment: Did you figure out that you had to copy the changes made during the wsconfig process into the httpd template in MAMP to keep it from clobbering changes made?